# React Native NavigationTransitioner example > RN 0.29

Tags: react-native

Does someone have an example of using NavigationTransitioner (part of NavigationExperimental) with ReactNative version 0.29 or greater.

I have no issues with v0.28 prior to the recent changes, but have not seen a version using the refactored NavigationTransitioner from v0.29 onwards.

Thank you,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is too broad; [questions asking only for generic examples are off-topic for Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291259/2747593). Instead, start writing code, and come back when you have a more specific problem. Be sure to show us [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

There are two example in the [UIExplorer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer) sample app included with react-native source code:

## [Stack of animated scenes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/js/NavigationExperimental/NavigationTransitioner-AnimatedView-example.js)

## [List of animated scenes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/js/NavigationExperimental/NavigationTransitioner-AnimatedView-pager-example.js)

Both examples use `<NavigationTransitioner />` and `<Animated.View />` to do the navigation.